# How to implement the MVVM-Pattern in SwiftUI? The View is not re-rendered

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, swiftui

i am learning SwiftUI and trying to implement a simple Timer with the MVVM-pattern. But the view of the Timer is not re-rendered. What is the problem?

```
// Timer Model

import Foundation

class TimerModel {
    let label: String = "Counter"
    var count: Int = 0
}
```

```
// Timer View Model

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timerModel: TimerModel = TimerModel()

    var label: String {
        return self.timerModel.label
    }

    var count: Int {
        return self.timerModel.count
    }

    func startTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.timerModel.count += 1
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
// Timer View 

import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TimerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var timerViewModel: TimerViewModel

    init() {
        self.timerViewModel = TimerViewModel()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.timerViewModel.label): \(self.timerViewModel.count)")
            Button(action: {
                self.timerViewModel.startTimer()
            }, label: {
                Text("Start")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerView()
    }
}
```

```
// Content View 

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TimerView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The count property of the Timer Model in the Timer View Model is changed every second, but the Timer View is not re-rendered. Thanks for any idea to implement the MVVM-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to change model to value type

```
struct TimerModel {
    let label: String = "Counter"
    var count: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Asperi. The counter is running :). Is the above code the right way to implement the MVVM-Pattern in larger projects? Why i need the value type struct instead of the reference type class?

Comment: If you change property of struct the entire struct is changed so `@Published` wrapper works, if property of object (of reference type) changed, the object (actually the reference) is not changed, so wrapper does not publish any events. The way in general is right.